# How to add SQL Server 2008 Express to List of Prerequisites

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008, installation, sql-server-2008-express

How can I add SQL Server 2008 Express to the list of Pre-requisites in Visual Studio 2008 SP1 MSI Installer Project.

Answer (score 2):

You have to download the SQL Server 2008 Bootstrapper from the MS Download Center (I think it is also included in the VS2008 Express Edition) and copy it into C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages. 
Each folder under 'Packages' is an entry of the list of Pre-requisites in Visual Studio 2008 SP1 MSI Installer Project.

BTW - If you want to create a custom Bootstrapper have a look at the article
[Authoring a Custom Bootstrapper Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730839(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

1. Install any flavor of Visual Studio 2008 Express SP1.
2. Go into the bootstrapper directory (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages) and rename both the SqlExpress2008 and WindowsInstaller4_5 directories.
3. Uninstall Visual Studio 2008 Express SP1 (IF you don't want to keep it).

Copied and pasted from: [Sql Server Express Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlexpress/archive/2008/09/12/faq-installing-the-sql-server-2008-express-clickonce-bootstrapper-for-visual-studio-2008-sp1.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The option of SQL Server 2008 Express is included in the prerequisete list

Comment: I don't have it in my Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2010 the option of SQL Server 2008 Express is included in the Prerequisites list.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, when Visual Studio 2008 was realesed, SQL Server 2008 doesn't exists yet, only the 2005 version.
So I think that you might not install the SQL Server 2005 when installing Visual Studio 2008, and after that, install SQL Server 2008 separately.

Regards.