# C# sql express 2008 not showing in the list of pre-requisites in setup project

Tags: c#, windows-installer, setup-project

I'm creating an installer via VS setup project, and I'd like to make sure sql express 2008 is installed if it is not already installed.

I right clicked on my installer project and go to Pre-requisites but SQL Server 2008 Express is not there.   2005 is listed, but I need 2008.

I installed SQL Server 2008 Express after Visual Studio.  What do I need to do to re-register with Visual Studio so it allows me to select SQL Server 2008 Express?

Comment: Doesn't it let you browse for a redistributable directly?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923439/how-to-add-sql-server-2008-express-to-list-of-prerequisites